# React-native Linking.openUrl doesn't open link to another screen

Tags: android, react-native, url, navigation, deep-linking

I have a react-native app and I'm trying to "redirect" user to another screen(based on url received from a deep linking", for example, if an user is on Screen A, then exits the app, clicks on the link, Screen A opens up and from Screen A the user should be redirected to the screen B. I'm getting the deep link on the screen A but can't redirect user to Screen B on android. My code:

```
Linking.openURL(deepLink)
```

The deeplink has this structure:

```
myApp://mainPage/address
```

When I use Linking.canOpenURL => it throws an error. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, any suggestion is appreciated.thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: posting here in case anyone else runs into the same issue - I changed `Linking.openURL(deepLink)` to `branch.openURL(deepLink)` and it worked

Comment: what's branch here? It's not clear.

Comment: @justbecause probably https://branch.io/

Comment: Where did you get `branch` from?

Comment: what is branch???????? I can't find it on react native nor react navigation